# add chromium-browser package in buildroot

Tags: linux, chromium, chromium-embedded, buildroot

Good Day Everyone,

does anyone here knows how to add chromium-browser package on buildroot? I have been looking around the net to add the chromium-browser package, I found several files in [Google Fiber Project](https://gfiber.googlesource.com/buildroot/+/master/package) and added the necessary files in my local repo but after the build process it wasn't added.
 I have found this [Forum](http://buildroot-busybox.2317881.n4.nabble.com/XWindow-Browser-anyone-td16075.html) where someone says chromium is not included on the official Buildroot.

Any comment/suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: great question - did you find a solution after all these years ?

Answer (score 1):

See the patch series at http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2018-June/223323.html which was recently posted to the Buildroot mailing list. It hasn't been merged due to some outstanding comments/issues, but it provides a start, and we hope to have this merged in the near future.